# I am stuck with an attribute error in Brownie Python

Tags: python, brownie

I wrote a simple code in brownie python but getting an Attribute error

```
from brownie import accounts
def deploy_simple_storage():
    account=accounts[0]
    print(account)
    pass

    def main():
        deploy_simple_storage()
        

        if _name_=="_main_":
            main()
```

above is the code and below is the terminal's message

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-<br>packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 65, in run
    raise AttributeError(f"Module '{name}' has
 no method '{method_name}'")
AttributeError: Module 'scripts.deploy' has no method 'main'
Terminating local RPC client...
PS C:\brownie_simple_storage>
```

Comment: As an aside `if _name_=="_main_"` should be `if __name__=="__main__"`, note the double underscores. Also not sure if it is just an issue with how the code was pasted into your question, but there are some indentation problems, for example `def main()` should be de-dented all the way to the left, same with `if __name__ == ...`

Comment: You have `main()` indented as a sub-function underneath `deploy_simple_storage()`.  I suspect that is wrong.

Comment: Got resolved,thanks a lot @John Gordon

Comment: Got resolved,thanks a lot @Cory Kramer